# Initialize Ruby codes error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I tried to run these codes:

```
class Dog    
   def set_name(name)
      @dogname = name
   end

   def get_name
      return @dogname
   end

   def talk
      return "awww"
   end

   def initialize(title, description)
      @title = title
      @description = description
   end    
end

doggy = Dog.new
doggy.set_name('Sam')
puts doggy.get_name
puts doggy.talk


bogart = Dog.new('The Book', 'The road not taken')
puts bogart.to_s
puts bogart.inspect
```

I did make sure every argument is correct. However, I got the following errors.

```
C:\Ruby200\bin\ruby.exe -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) C:/Users/Todd/RubymineProjects/untitled1/test.rb
C:/Users/Todd/RubymineProjects/untitled1/test.rb:15:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (0 for 2) (ArgumentError)
    from C:/Users/Todd/RubymineProjects/untitled1/test.rb:22:in `new'
    from C:/Users/Todd/RubymineProjects/untitled1/test.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Tried my best can't find the issue. Any idea where I miss?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion. Please stop asking for unrelated debugging help in the comments below each answer. If you have a new question, [ask it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Dog

  def set_name(name)
    @dogname = name
  end

  def get_name
    return @dogname
  end

  def talk
    return "awww"
  end

  def initialize(title, description)
    @title = title
    @description = description
  end

end

#That will cause an error because your new method have two arguments.
doggy = Dog.new



bogart = Dog.new('The Book', 'The road not taken')
bogart.set_name('Sam')
puts bogart.get_name
puts bogart.talk
puts bogart.to_s
puts bogart.inspect
```

Answer (score 1):

Object creation — you are missing argument passing to the `initialize` method.

`doggy = Dog.new`   **should be** `doggy = Dog.new('argument1', 'argument2')`

Answer (score 1):

in `Dog` class you have overrided constructer `initialize` with two arguments. so when ever you want to create instance for that class you have to pass `2` arguments for that.
here `doggy = Dog.new` you are trying create instance with out any arguments. so `initialize` method thorws an error.

Answer (score 1):

See this line in your code:

```
doggy = Dog.new
```

here you have not passed the arguments title, description which is causing the error.

Either pass some arguments when you are creating an object of Dog class or change your initialize method like this:

```
  def initialize(title=nil, description=nil)
    @title = title
    @description = description
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

You may to read more carfuly the error code. This line

> `initialize': wrong number of arguments (0 for 2) (ArgumentError)

tells you the reason for `ArgumentError`.

You pass the 0 arguments to `initialize` method in Dog `class` and this method need 2 arguments.

```
Dog.new # 0 arguments

# your method in Dog class
def initialize(title, description)
  @title = title
  @description = description
end
```

If you need to send `nil` arguments, you must define the default value on variables like this

```
def initialize(title = nil, description = nil)
  @title, @description = title, description
end
```

so your code will looks like this.

```
class Dog
  def initialize(title = nil, description = nil)
    @title = title
    @description = description
  end

  def set_name(name)
    @dogname = name
  end

  def get_name
    @dogname
  end

  def talk
    "awww"
  end
end
```

I hope this helps

BTW: look here for more redable codes [Ruby Styleguide](https://github.com/styleguide/ruby)